# DTSX: Failure importing configuration file

Tags: ssis, configuration-files

I'm trying to run a DTSX package on my development environment on local in Visual Studio and getting following error while executing it.

`Failure importing configuration file: "C:\ProgramData\ssis packages\Database Server.dtsConfig;".`

Another error is: `SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D`
I've checked that file exists at the above mentioned path.

Comment: How are you running the package when you get the failure?  In the development environment (Visual Studio) on your desktop, or as a package deployed to a server?  This affects what machine the package runs on, so that the C:\... path to the config file might not exist.

Comment: Development environment on local in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I've tried messing up my config file in various ways, but I never get precisely the error message you do.  I'm using SSIS2008, VS 20008 though - you're probably on a more recent version.

You seem to have a semi-colon ";" at the end of your file path.  Unless that's a feature added in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check any variable which is listed in config file but not defined in SSIS variable list.

Comment: Probably could be a comment.